# Is it normal for it = map.find (element) == map.end() have it->second?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I was very surprised getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception on iterating by non-existing element in map. It does not fall down, when I try to get `it->second`, on iterator, which is actually `map.end()`. It does fall down, trying to reach some bad memory. 
I wonder a lot how iterator end is realized, and how to get out of problems like this. Is always checking `if (iterator == map.end ())` the only way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map> 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    map<int, map<int, bool>> big_map;
    map<int, bool> small_map;

    small_map.insert(make_pair(1,1));
    big_map.insert(make_pair(1, small_map));

    auto non_exist = big_map.find(0);
    for (auto i = non_exist->second.begin(); i != non_exist->second.end(); ++i) {
        cout << i->second << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

> 1
>   1
>   0
>   and  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`non_exist->second` is undefined behaviour when `non_exist  == big_map.end()`. You must check that before embarking on the loop.

Answer (score 1):

That's not enough, you should check `non_exist != big_map.end()` before.

```
auto non_exist = big_map.find(0);

if (non_exist != big_map.end())
{
    for (auto i = non_exist->second.begin(); i != non_exist->second.end(); ++i) {
        cout << i->second << endl;
    }
}
```